# iOS 17.4 Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.storekitd"

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

When upgrading to iOS 17.4 StoreKit stop to work. Can't get products from App Store.
But with iOS 17.2 everything works fine.

For example

```
  func getProducts() async {
        do {
            products = try await Product.products(
                for: [
                    IAPProducts.report.rawValue,
                    IAPProducts.report5.rawValue,
                    IAPProducts.report10.rawValue,
                    IAPProducts.report50.rawValue
                ]
            )
        } catch {
            products = []
        }
    }
```

return

> [1142_SK2] Failed in XPC product request products(IDs: ["report, report5, report10, report50"]): Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.storekitd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.storekitd}

All features return **Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.storekitd"**

> <SKPaymentQueue: 0x3025a8d00>: Error in remote proxy while checking server queue: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.storekitd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.storekitd}